# playbackRate on AUDIO and pitch

Tags: javascript, html, html5-audio, pitch-shifting

Little bit of background:
People like games.
People use the internet.
The internet needs games.
Games use sound.
HTML5 has `<audio>`.

Okay, all good so far.

Recently I discovered - to my surprise - that IE9 actually supports playbackRate. I eagerly gave it a try. Even more surprising, it actually worked. I tried the same in Chrome, and while it worked it was horribly grating when I set it to `0.5`. I've already ditched Firefox because it doesn't support MP3.

Moving on, here's my question: both IE and Chrome apply pitch correction when changing the playbackRate. IE does a great job, Chrome does a horrible one. Either way, I don't want this, I ***want*** the sounds to change pitch. With that kind of power I can delete 650 files I had to procedurally generate to have an alternate pitch, and will have far more freedom with my projects. Heck, I could even make a MOD track player in HTML5 (minus the Effects channel) if I really wanted to.

So, is there anything in the HTML5 specification that allows me to turn pitch correction off, and just have the sound be played as if the samples had literally been stretched apart of squeezed together?

Comment: seriously verbose question :D

Comment: Have you checked the HTML5 Aduio API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's currenly nothing in the HTML5 specification that allows you such fine tuning with audio.

But.

Why do you care about "power" and "freedom with projects" when you're already limiting yourself by deciding to ditch Firefox? Incidentally Opera also doesn't support MP3.

Unless of course it's a personal project where no-one but yourself will be using it and therefore it's a moot point. In which case if you want to target Chrome for example, you could check out the [Web Audio API](https://dvcs.w3.org/hg/audio/raw-file/tip/webaudio/specification.html) which might have something you want.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Mozilla bug tracker issue on implementing playbackRate](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=495040)

> WebKit solves this by exporting an additional (prefixed) attribute
>   "preservesPitch" (proposed to the WhatWG here:
>   http://lists.whatwg.org/htdig.cgi/whatwg-whatwg.org/2009-July/021100.html)

Presumably you can set preservesPitch (webkitPreservesPitch for webkit) to false to turn off this feature in Webkit at least. I'm not familiar with other browser support for this property.

Comment: This is now supported in FireFox per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

Answer (score 6):

Chrome currently supports the Web Audio API ( http://www.w3.org/TR/webaudio/ ) which has a playbackRate audioParam that you can set. It's not as simple as the `<audio>` tag, but allows for all sorts of cool stuff. I'm currently using it to play with pitch-shifting / time-stretching distortion.

Here's an example of what you could do:

```
    //build a request and fire it off
    speedChanger.loader = (function(){

      var _request       = new XMLHttpRequest(),

          _handleRequest = function(url){
            _request.open('GET',url,true);
            _request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
            _request.onload = function(){
              SpeedChanger.audioGraph.context.decodeAudioData(_request.response, function(buffer){
                _loadedBuffer = buffer;
                SpeedChanger.audioGraph.setBuffer(buffer);
                SpeedChanger.audioGraph.setBufferCache(buffer);

              },function(){//error stuff});
            };
            _request.send();
          };

      _handleRequest("audio/file.mp3");

  }());//loader

  grainTable.audioGraph = (function(){
    var _context = new webkitAudioContext(),         //this is the container for your entire audio graph
        _source = _context.createBufferSource(),     //your buffer will sit here
        _bufferCache,                                //buffer needs to be re-initialized before every play, so we'll cache what we've loaded here

        //for chaching / retrieving the buffer
        _getBufferCache = function(){
          return _bufferCache;  
        },
        _setBufferCache = function(_sound){
          _bufferCache = _sound;
        },

        //for setting the current instance of the buffer 
        _setBuffer = function(_sound){
          _source.buffer = _sound;
        },

        _setPlaybackRate = function(rate){
          _source.playbackRate.value = rate;
        },

        _setRate = function(myRate){
            _rate = myRate;
        }

        //play it
        _playSound = function(){

          _source.noteOff(0);                       //call noteOff to stop any instance already playing before we play ours

          _source = _context.createBufferSource();  //init the source
          _setBuffer(_bufferCache);                 //re-set the buffer

          _setPlaybackRate(_rate);                  //here's your playBackRate check

          _source.connect(_context.destination);    //connect to the speakers 
          _source.noteOn(0);                        //pass in 0 to play immediately
        },

}

    return{

      context        :_context,
      setBuffer      :_setBuffer,
      setBufferCache :_setBufferCache,
      playSound      :_playSound,
      setRate        :_setRate

    }

  }());//audioGraph
```

Comment: any progress on your pitch-shifting / time-stretching algo? I can only time stretch one track or I have to merge multiple tracks but that's not ideal because I lose the ability to change gain on each track; also i can't pause or resume...

Comment: I've gotten side-tracked by work, sadly. My last attempt was using multiple delayNodes to try and re-create multiple tape-heads. This seemed to be eliminating some of the clicking that I was experiencing. But unfortunately the algorithm is far from ideal at this point.

Comment: Not yet. But this looks promising. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I have finally gotten it to work: had to tweak the soundtouch ;i'm pre-rendering al my tracks; using offline context and context.render functions. I can still play/pause/stop/change gain of each track