# How to change pitch of embedded sound on page?

Tags: javascript, embed

Can I change pitch of embedded sound on page with JavaScript?

I have simple `embed` tag:

```
<embed src="tone.wav" autostart="true" />
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't.

`<embed>` uses whatever player the user has on their system, and there is not a consistent API nor feature set.

What you **can** do is [use the Web Audio API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610497/362536).