# Html 5 video / audio pitch

Tags: html, video, html5-video

I am facing the problem i want to use the html5 video player, but with a pitched sound.

what i have tried so far is setting the playbackrate of the html5 player higher and then lower, but this only messes with the playback rate (as it actually tells us). It does not change the pitch of the audio of this html5 video-player.

I know this google chrome plugin:
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pitch-shifter-html5-video/mpmkclglcbkjchakihfpblainfncennj?hl=en-GB

This does change the pitch of html5 players, but i dont know how to do the same but then without any plugins and just programmatically do this.

I have looked through the docs of HTML 5 video:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement

but this does not give me an answer.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12610497/1569675

Comment: just curious but why not adjust pitch in post production with your video editor, and play it as is?

Comment: @Offbeatmammal Thanks for this suggestion, i will ook into this.
RobertWade Because i dont like pitching 1500+ songs manually

Answer (score 0):

Pitch cannot be independently adjusted in HTMLMediaElement

https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1833

It might be possible to extract the audio track to Web Audio but that looks too complicated. https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-biquadfilternode-frequency